# Next.js Link Component Error: Failed prop type: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object`, but got `undefined`

Tags: javascript, next.js, error-handling, hyperlink

**Description**:

I'm encountering an error in my Next.js project related to the `Link` component. I've reviewed my code and tried various solutions, but I'm still unable to resolve the issue.

**Code**:

Layout.js

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Nav from "@/components/Navbar";
import { Dialog } from "@headlessui/react";
import { Bars3Icon, XMarkIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import {ChatBubbleLeftRightIcon} from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import { CurrencyRupeeIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import { ShoppingBagIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import { UserGroupIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { LockClosedIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import { FireIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";

const navigation = [
  { name: "", href: "#" },
  { name: "", href: "#" },
  { name: "", href: "#" },
];

const features = [
 //data
];

const people = [
  //data
];

const links = [
 //data
];
const stats = [
  //data
];

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(false);
  const [mobileMenuOpen, setMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  



  async function logout() {
    await router.push("/");
    await signOut();
  }

  if (!session) {
  return (
      <div className="bg-white">
        <Head>
          <title>Prakriti Bazaar</title>
        </Head>
        
        <header className="absolute inset-x-0 top-0 z-50">
          <nav
            className="flex items-center justify-between p-6 lg:px-8"
            aria-label="Global"
          >
            <div className="flex lg:flex-1">
              <Link href="#" className="-m-1.5 p-1.5">
                <span className="sr-only">Prakriti Bazaar</span>
                <Image
                  className="h-10 w-auto"
                  src="/logo.png"
                  alt=""
                  width={1000}
                  height={1000}
                />
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="flex lg:hidden">
              <button
                type="button"
                className="-m-2.5 inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2.5 text-gray-700"
                onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(true)}
              >
                <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                <Bars3Icon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="hidden lg:flex lg:gap-x-12">
              {navigation.map((item) => (
                <Link
                  key={item.name}
                  href={item.href}
                  className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900"
                >
                  {item.name}
                </Link>
              ))}
            </div>
            <div className="hidden lg:flex lg:flex-1 lg:justify-end">
              <Link
                href="/api/auth/signin"
                className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900"
              >
                Log in <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <Dialog
            as="div"
            className="lg:hidden"
            open={mobileMenuOpen}
            onClose={setMobileMenuOpen}
          >
            <div className="fixed inset-0 z-50" />
            <Dialog.Panel className="fixed inset-y-0 right-0 z-50 w-full overflow-y-auto bg-white px-6 py-6 sm:max-w-sm sm:ring-1 sm:ring-gray-900/10">
             <div className="flex lg:flex-1">
<Link href="/" className="-m-1.5 p-1.5">
    <span className="sr-only">Prakriti Bazaar</span>
    <Image
      className="h-10 w-auto"
      src="/logo.png"
      alt=""
      width={1000}
      height={1000}
    />
  </Link>


                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="-m-2.5 rounded-md p-2.5 text-gray-700"
                  onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(false)}
                >
                  <span className="sr-only">Close menu</span>
                  <XMarkIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-6 flow-root">
                <div className="-my-6 divide-y divide-gray-500/10">
                  <div className="space-y-2 py-6">
                    {navigation.map((item) => (
                      <Link
                        key={item.name}
                        href={item.href}
                        className="-mx-3 block rounded-lg px-3 py-2 text-base font-semibold leading-7 text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50"
                      >
                        {item.name}
                      </Link>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                  <div className="py-6">
                    <Link
                      href="/api/auth/signin"
                      className="-mx-3 block rounded-lg px-3 py-2.5 text-base font-semibold leading-7 text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50"
                    >
                      Log in
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Dialog.Panel>
          </Dialog>
        </header>

        <div className="relative isolate px-6 pt-14 lg:px-8">
          <div
            className="absolute inset-x-0 -top-40 -z-10 transform-gpu overflow-hidden blur-3xl sm:-top-80"
            aria-hidden="true"
          >
            <div
              className="relative left-[calc(50%-11rem)] aspect-[1155/678] w-[36.125rem] -translate-x-1/2 rotate-[30deg] bg-gradient-to-tr from-[#80ff95] to-[#89fc92] opacity-30 sm:left-[calc(50%-30rem)] sm:w-[72.1875rem]"
              style={{
                clipPath:
                  "polygon(74.1% 44.1%, 100% 61.6%, 97.5% 26.9%, 85.5% 0.1%, 80.7% 2%, 72.5% 32.5%, 60.2% 62.4%, 52.4% 68.1%, 47.5% 58.3%, 45.2% 34.5%, 27.5% 76.7%, 0.1% 64.9%, 17.9% 100%, 27.6% 76.8%, 76.1% 97.7%, 74.1% 44.1%)",
              }}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl py-32 sm:py-48 lg:py-56">
            <div className="hidden sm:mb-8 sm:flex sm:justify-center">
              <div className="relative rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm leading-6 text-gray-600 ring-1 ring-gray-900/10 hover:ring-gray-900/20">
                Cultivating Harmony ️
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="text-center">
              <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-6xl">
                Welcome to Prakriti Bazaar!!
              </h1>
              <p className="mt-6 text-lg leading-8 text-gray-600">
                From Fields to Festivities
              </p>
              <div className="mt-10 flex items-center justify-center gap-x-6">
                <Link
                  href="/api/auth/signin"
                  className="rounded-md bg-green-600 px-3.5 py-2.5 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-green-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-green-600"
                >
                  Get started
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            className="absolute inset-x-0 top-[calc(100%-13rem)] -z-10 transform-gpu overflow-hidden blur-3xl sm:top-[calc(100%-30rem)]"
            aria-hidden="true"
          >
            <div
              className="relative left-[calc(50%+3rem)] aspect-[1155/678] w-[36.125rem] -translate-x-1/2 bg-gradient-to-tr from-[#80ff95] to-[#89fc92] opacity-30 sm:left-[calc(50%+36rem)] sm:w-[72.1875rem]"
              style={{
                clipPath:
                  "polygon(74.1% 44.1%, 100% 61.6%, 97.5% 26.9%, 85.5% 0.1%, 80.7% 2%, 72.5% 32.5%, 60.2% 62.4%, 52.4% 68.1%, 47.5% 58.3%, 45.2% 34.5%, 27.5% 76.7%, 0.1% 64.9%, 17.9% 100%, 27.6% 76.8%, 76.1% 97.7%, 74.1% 44.1%)",
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="bg-white py-24 sm:py-32">
          <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl lg:text-center">
              <h2 className="text-base font-semibold leading-7 text-green-600">
                Discover the Exciting Features of 
              </h2>
              <p className="mt-2 text-3xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-4xl">
                Your Urban Agriculture Hub
              </p>
              <p className="mt-6 text-lg leading-8 text-gray-600">
                PrakritiBazaar is a vibrant online marketplace dedicated to urban agriculture and sustainable living. We believe in bringing the bounty of nature closer to urban dwellers, fostering a deeper connection with the environment. Whether you are a seasoned gardener or just starting out, PrakritiBazaar provides a platform to explore, buy, and sell a wide array of agricultural products right from the heart of the city.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="mx-auto mt-16 max-w-2xl sm:mt-20 lg:mt-24 lg:max-w-4xl">
              <dl className="grid max-w-xl grid-cols-1 gap-x-8 gap-y-10 lg:max-w-none lg:grid-cols-2 lg:gap-y-16">
                {features.map((feature) => (
                  <div key={feature.name} className="relative pl-16">
                    <dt className="text-base font-semibold leading-7 text-gray-900">
                      <div className="absolute left-0 top-0 flex h-10 w-10 items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-green-600">
                        <feature.icon
                          className="h-6 w-6 text-white"
                          aria-hidden="true"
                        />
                      </div>
                      {feature.name}
                    </dt>
                    <dd className="mt-2 text-base leading-7 text-gray-600">
                      {feature.description}
                    </dd>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </dl>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="bg-white py-24 sm:py-32">
          <div className="mx-auto grid max-w-7xl gap-x-8 gap-y-20 px-6 lg:px-8 xl:grid-cols-3">
            <div className="max-w-2xl">
              <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-4xl">
                Meet our dynamic leaders at PrakritiBazaar
              </h2>
              <p className="mt-6 text-lg leading-8 text-gray-600">
               where Shivanshu, our skilled Full-Stack Web Developer, has brought our website to life with seamless functionality and beautiful design, while Archit, our talented Video Editor and Graphic Designer, has shaped our visual identity through a distinctive logo and informative tutorials. Together, they spearhead our mission to empower urban gardeners and enthusiasts in creating a greener, more sustainable urban lifestyle.
              </p>
            </div>
            <ul
              role="list"
              className="grid gap-x-8 gap-y-12 sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-y-16 xl:col-span-2"
            >
              {people.map((person) => (
                <li key={person.name}>
                  <div className="flex items-center gap-x-6">
                    <Image
                      className="h-16 w-16 rounded-full"
                      src={person.imageUrl}
                      alt=""
                      width={900}
                      height={900}
                    />
                    <div>
                      <h3 className="text-base font-semibold leading-7 tracking-tight text-gray-900">
                        {person.name}
                      </h3>
                      <p className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-green-600">
                        {person.role}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        
    <section className="relative isolate overflow-hidden bg-white px-6 py-24 sm:py-32 lg:px-8">
  <div className="absolute inset-0 -z-10 bg-[radial-gradient(45rem_50rem_at_top,theme(colors.green.100),white)] opacity-20" />
  <div className="absolute inset-y-0 right-1/2 -z-10 mr-16 w-[200%] origin-bottom-left skew-x-[-30deg] bg-white shadow-xl shadow-green-600/10 ring-1 ring-green-50 sm:mr-28 lg:mr-0 xl:mr-16 xl:origin-center" />
  <div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl lg:max-w-4xl">
    <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold text-center text-gray-900 mb-10">Our Mission</h1>
    <figure>
      <blockquote className="text-center text-xl font-semibold leading-8 text-gray-900 sm:text-2xl sm:leading-9">
        <p>
          “At PrakritiBazaar, we envision a future where every urban household is connected to nature through sustainable agricultural practices. Together, we strive to create greener, healthier, and more self-sufficient communities. We invite you to join us on this journey towards a more sustainable and harmonious urban life.”
        </p>
      </blockquote>
      <figcaption className="mt-10">
        <img
          className="mx-auto h-10 w-10 rounded-full"
          src="shivanshu.jpeg"
          alt=""
        />
        <div className="mt-4 flex items-center justify-center space-x-3 text-base">
          <div className="font-semibold text-gray-900">Shivanshu Bhashkar</div>
          <svg viewBox="0 0 2 2" width={3} height={3} aria-hidden="true" className="fill-gray-900">
            <circle cx={1} cy={1} r={1} />
          </svg>
          <div className="text-gray-600">Developer of PrakritiBazaar</div>
        </div>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>


        <div className="bg-white">
          <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl py-24 sm:px-6 sm:py-32 lg:px-8">
            <div className="relative isolate overflow-hidden bg-gray-900 px-6 pt-16 shadow-2xl sm:rounded-3xl sm:px-16 md:pt-24 lg:flex lg:gap-x-20 lg:px-24 lg:pt-0">
              <svg
                viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"
                className="absolute left-1/2 top-1/2 -z-10 h-[64rem] w-[64rem] -translate-y-1/2 [mask-image:radial-gradient(closest-side,white,transparent)] sm:left-full sm:-ml-80 lg:left-1/2 lg:ml-0 lg:-translate-x-1/2 lg:translate-y-0"
                aria-hidden="true"
              >
                <circle
                  cx={512}
                  cy={512}
                  r={512}
                  fill="url(#759c1415-0410-454c-8f7c-9a820de03641)"
                  fillOpacity="0.7"
                />
                <defs>
                  <radialGradient id="759c1415-0410-454c-8f7c-9a820de03641">
                    <stop stopColor="#F9FFF9" />
                    <stop offset={1} stopColor="#16A34A" />
                  </radialGradient>
                </defs>
              </svg>
              <div className="mx-auto max-w-md text-center lg:mx-0 lg:flex-auto lg:py-32 lg:text-left">
                <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold tracking-tight text-white sm:text-4xl">
    Cultivating Nature&apos;s Bounty, Connecting Communities
</h2>
                <p className="mt-6 text-lg leading-8 text-gray-300">
                 At PrakritiBazaar, we have created a vibrant online platform that celebrates the beauty and abundance of nature. Our marketplace is dedicated to urban agriculture, where farmers, growers, and nature enthusiasts come together to share the fruits of their labor and a deep passion for cultivating the land.
                </p>
                <div className="mt-10 flex items-center justify-center gap-x-6 lg:justify-start">
                  <Link
                    href="/api/auth/signin"
                    className="rounded-md bg-white px-3.5 py-2.5 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-100 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-white"
                  >
                    Get started
                  </Link>
                    <Link
                    href="mailto:prakritibazaar@gmail.com"
                    className="rounded-md bg-white px-3.5 py-2.5 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-100 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-white"
                  >
                    Contact Support
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="relative mt-16 h-80 lg:mt-8">
                <Image
                  className="absolute left-0 top-0 w-[57rem] max-w-none rounded-md bg-white/5 ring-1 ring-white/10"
                  src="/Screenshot.png"
                  alt="App screenshot"
                  width={1824}
                  height={1080}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
     <div className="bg-white text-white min-h-screen">
      <Nav />
   <main >    {children} </main>
 
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Error Message**:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJnau.png)
Uncaught Error: Failed prop type: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `undefined` instead.

**What I've Tried**:

- Checked for correct imports of the Link component.
- Ensured that the `href` prop is properly passed to the Link component.
- Reviewed the component tree to ensure there are no conflicting props or missing values.

**Additional Information**:

- This error occurs specifically in the component where I use the Link component.
- I've also tried creating a new Next.js project and transferring the code, but the issue persists.

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551); and please do not just send us to external repositories to see the relevant code either, a proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question.

Comment: @CBroe my code is very long that's why i done this

Comment: You are supposed to _reduce_ it to the relevant parts, not just dump all of it here for us to go look through.

Comment: ok i understand